# PyTorch torch.max over multiple dimensions

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, max, pytorch, tensor

Have tensor like :`x.shape = [3, 2, 2]`.

```py
import torch

x = torch.tensor([
    [[-0.3000, -0.2926],[-0.2705, -0.2632]],
    [[-0.1821, -0.1747],[-0.1526, -0.1453]],
    [[-0.0642, -0.0568],[-0.0347, -0.0274]]
])
```

I need to take `.max()` over the 2nd and 3rd dimensions. I expect some like this `[-0.2632, -0.1453, -0.0274]` as output. I tried to use: `x.max(dim=(1,2))`, but this causes an error.

Comment: I updated my answer, because the PR I mentioned is now merged and this feature is available in the nightly release. See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Now, you can do this. The [PR was merged](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/commit/bcec8cc3f9b14a79895af026891e9fd5f4a01b0a) (Aug 28 2020) and it is now available in the nightly release.

Simply use [`torch.amax()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.amax.html):

```py
import torch

x = torch.tensor([
    [[-0.3000, -0.2926],[-0.2705, -0.2632]],
    [[-0.1821, -0.1747],[-0.1526, -0.1453]],
    [[-0.0642, -0.0568],[-0.0347, -0.0274]]
])

print(torch.amax(x, dim=(1, 2)))

# Output:
# >>> tensor([-0.2632, -0.1453, -0.0274])
```

---

**Original Answer**

As of today (April 11, 2020), there is no way to do `.min()` or `.max()` over multiple dimensions in PyTorch. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/28213) about it that you can follow and see if it ever gets implemented. A workaround in your case would be:

```py
import torch

x = torch.tensor([
    [[-0.3000, -0.2926],[-0.2705, -0.2632]],
    [[-0.1821, -0.1747],[-0.1526, -0.1453]],
    [[-0.0642, -0.0568],[-0.0347, -0.0274]]
])

print(x.view(x.size(0), -1).max(dim=-1))

# output:
# >>> values=tensor([-0.2632, -0.1453, -0.0274]),
# >>> indices=tensor([3, 3, 3]))
```

So, if you need only the values: `x.view(x.size(0), -1).max(dim=-1).values`.

If `x` is not a contiguous tensor, then `.view()` will fail. In this case, you should use `.reshape()` instead.

---

**Update August 26, 2020**

This feature is being implemented in [PR#43092](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/43092) and the functions will be called `amin` and `amax`. They will return only the values. This is probably being merged soon, so you might be able to access these functions on the nightly build by the time you're reading this :) Have fun.

Comment: thanks. it works, but need use reshape insted view for avoid error in my case

Comment: @iGero ok, I'll add this note on the answer just in case :) glad it helped

Comment: I tried this with pytorch version 1.5.0 and 1.6.0, but there was no method `torch.amax`. Can you validate that? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @zwep as I said in the answer, this function is currently available in the *nightly release*. Therefore, you have to upgrade to it if you want to have access to amax, or wait until the next stable release, i.e., 1.7.0.

Comment: @Berriel ah sorry, I did not know which version was related to the nightly release. Although I dont know if you can talk of a version in such a case

Comment: @zwep don't worry. Well, it is called nightly build/release :) you can find instructions on how to install in the official PyTorch website. It is straightforward. Let me know if you have any problem.

Answer (score 6):

Although the [solution of Berriel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61157056/2956066) solves this specific question, I thought adding some explanation might help everyone to shed some light on the trick that's employed here, so that it can be adapted for (m)any other dimensions.

Let's start by inspecting the shape of the input tensor `x`:

```
In [58]: x.shape   
Out[58]: torch.Size([3, 2, 2])
```

So, we have a 3D tensor of shape `(3, 2, 2)`. Now, as per OP's question, we need to compute `maximum` of the values in the tensor along both 1<sup>st</sup> and 2<sup>nd</sup> dimensions. As of this writing, the `torch.max()`'s `dim` argument supports only `int`. So, we can't use a tuple. Hence, we will use the following trick, which I will call as,

**The Flatten & Max Trick**: since we want to compute `max` over both 1<sup>st</sup> and 2<sup>nd</sup> dimensions, we will flatten both of these dimensions to a single dimension and leave the 0<sup>th</sup> dimension untouched. This is exactly what is happening by doing:

```
In [61]: x.flatten().reshape(x.shape[0], -1).shape   
Out[61]: torch.Size([3, 4])   # 2*2 = 4
```

So, now we have shrinked the 3D tensor to a 2D tensor (i.e. matrix).

```
In [62]: x.flatten().reshape(x.shape[0], -1) 
Out[62]:
tensor([[-0.3000, -0.2926, -0.2705, -0.2632],
        [-0.1821, -0.1747, -0.1526, -0.1453],
        [-0.0642, -0.0568, -0.0347, -0.0274]])
```

Now, we can simply apply `max` over the 1<sup>st</sup> dimension (i.e. in this case, first dimension is also the last dimension), since the flattened dimensions resides in that dimension.

```
In [65]: x.flatten().reshape(x.shape[0], -1).max(dim=1)    # or: `dim = -1`
Out[65]: 
torch.return_types.max(
values=tensor([-0.2632, -0.1453, -0.0274]),
indices=tensor([3, 3, 3]))
```

We got 3 values in the resultant tensor since we had 3 rows in the matrix.

---

Now, on the other hand if you want to compute `max` over 0<sup>th</sup> and 1<sup>st</sup> dimensions, you'd do:

```
In [80]: x.flatten().reshape(-1, x.shape[-1]).shape 
Out[80]: torch.Size([6, 2])    # 3*2 = 6

In [79]: x.flatten().reshape(-1, x.shape[-1]) 
Out[79]: 
tensor([[-0.3000, -0.2926],
        [-0.2705, -0.2632],
        [-0.1821, -0.1747],
        [-0.1526, -0.1453],
        [-0.0642, -0.0568],
        [-0.0347, -0.0274]])
```

Now, we can simply apply `max` over the 0<sup>th</sup> dimension since that is the result of our flattening. ((also, from our original shape of (`3, 2, 2`), after taking max over first 2 dimensions, we should get two values as result.)

```
In [82]: x.flatten().reshape(-1, x.shape[-1]).max(dim=0) 
Out[82]: 
torch.return_types.max(
values=tensor([-0.0347, -0.0274]),
indices=tensor([5, 5]))
```

In a similar vein, you can adapt this approach to multiple dimensions and other reduction functions such as `min`.

---

**Note**: I'm following the terminology of 0-based dimensions (`0, 1, 2, 3, ...`) just to be consistent with PyTorch usage and the code.

Comment: oh, getting clear a bit. could you please specify what is "result of flattening"? i would appreciate, thanks!

Comment: *Flattening* always returns an 1D tensor of size resulting from the multiplication of the individual dimensions in the original shape (i.e., 3*2*2 here with tensor `x`)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to use the `torch.max()` function to get the indices of the max entry in a 2D tensor, you can do:

```
max_i_vals, max_i_indices = torch.max(x, 0)
print('max_i_vals, max_i_indices: ', max_i_vals, max_i_indices)
max_j_index = torch.max(max_i_vals, 0)[1]
print('max_j_index: ', max_j_index)
max_index = [max_i_indices[max_j_index], max_j_index]
print('max_index: ', max_index)
```

In testing, the above printed out for me:

```
max_i_vals: tensor([0.7930, 0.7144, 0.6985, 0.7349, 0.9162, 0.5584, 1.4777, 0.8047, 0.9008, 1.0169, 0.6705, 0.9034, 1.1159, 0.8852, 1.0353], grad_fn=\<MaxBackward0>)   
max_i_indices: tensor([ 5,  8, 10,  6, 13, 14,  5,  6,  6,  6, 13,  4, 13, 13, 11])  
max_j_index:  tensor(6)  
max_index:  [tensor(5), tensor(6)]
```

This approach can be extended for 3 dimensions. While not as visually pleasing as other answers in this post, this answer shows that the problem can be solved using only the `torch.max()` function (though I do agree built-in support for `torch.max()` over multiple dimensions would be a boon).

**FOLLOW UP**
I stumbled upon a [similar question in the PyTorch forums](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/get-indices-of-the-max-of-a-2d-tensor/82150/2) and the poster ptrblck offered this line of code as a solution for getting the indices of the maximal entry in the tensor x:

```
x = (x==torch.max(x)).nonzero()
```

Not only does this one-liner work with N-dimensional tensors without needing adjustments to the code, but it is also much faster than the approach I wrote of above (at least 2:1 ratio) and faster than the accepted answer (about 3:2 ratio) according to my benchmarks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use torch <= 1.10, please use this custom max function

```
def torch_max(x,dim):
    s1 = [i for i in range(len(x.shape)) if i not in dim] 
    s2 = [i for i in range(len(x.shape)) if i in dim]
    x2 = x.permute(tuple(s1+s2))
    s = [d for (i,d) in enumerate(x.shape) if i not in dim] + [-1]
    x2 = torch.reshape(x2, tuple(s))
    max,_ = x2.max(-1)
    return max
```

Then run like

```
print(torch_max(x, dim=(1, 2)))
```